# Is there an elegant way to deal with inserting rows with duplicate identifiers?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to insert some rows into my table that have the same unique identifier, but all the other fields are different (the rows represent points on a map, and they just happen to have the same name). The final result I'd like to end up with is to somehow modify the offending rows to have unique identifiers (adding on some incrementing number to the identifier, like "name0", "name1", "name2", etc.) during the insertion command.

I'm aware of Postgres's recent addition of "ON CONFLICT" support, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

According to the [Postgres 9.6 Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-insert.html):

> The optional ON CONFLICT clause specifies an **alternative action** to raising a unique violation or exclusion constraint violation error. For each individual row proposed for insertion, either the insertion proceeds, or ... the alternative conflict_action is taken. ...ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE updates the existing row that conflicts with the row proposed for insertion as its **alternative action**.

What I would like to do is 1) either modify the offending row or the insertion itself **and** 2) proceed with the insertion (instead of replacing it with an update, like the ON CONFLICT feature does). Is there an elegant way of accomplishing this? Or am I going to need to write something more complex?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
create table my_table
( 
  name text primary key,
  some_column varchar
);

create sequence my_table_seq;
```

The sequence is used to assign a unique suffix to the new row's PK column.

The "insert on conflict insert modified" behaviour can be done like this:

```
with data (name, some_column) as (
  values ('foo', 'bar')
), inserted as (
  insert into my_table
  select *
  from data
  on conflict (name) do nothing
  returning *
)
insert into my_table (name, some_column)
select concat(name, '_', nextval('my_table_seq')), some_column
from data
where not exists (select 1 from inserted);
```

The first time you insert a value into the PK column, the insert (in the CTE "inserted") just proceeds. The final `insert` won't insert anything because the `where not exists ()` prevents that as the `inserted` returned one row.

The second time you run this, the first insert won't insert anything, and thus the second (final) insert will.

There is one drawback though: if something was inserted by the "inserted" CTE, the the overall statement will report "0 rows affected" because the final insert is the one "driving" this information.